# In SAS, does the using the GLM statement ABSORB invalidate the standard errors of the parameter estimates?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, panel-data, sas, fixed-effects-model, covariance-matrix

SAS provides a handy tool for handling panel models with a large number of groups by 'absorbing' those groups (PROC GLM; ABSORB). My understanding is that it factors the effect of the absorbed parameters out of the data before estimating the remaining parameters. It seems like this may invalidate the standard errors of the parameter estimates. The variance covariance matrix would not be calculated with the full set of parameters. Hence, we would be calculating the variance covariance matrix conditional on the absorbed parameters, where we would really want the unconditional variance. Am I misunderstanding what is going on here? I haven't found any good explanations in the help files.

Comment: BrentL given that the SAS code- and SAS help-related aspect of the question would be [off topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (see under programming there), could you explain what "absorbing" is? If you clarify that, the remainder of the question (about how it impacts standard errors) should be on topic.

Answer (score 5):

In SAS, if you `ABSORB` a variable in `PROC GLM`, it adjusts its effects but does not include it in the VCV matrix of the estimated parameters. This means that the other parameter standard errors and other inferential statistics (such as confidence intervals and p-values) are *conditional* on the absorbed variable. They do not account for the variability created by evaluating the impact of the absorbed variable.

This conditional method may result in underestimating of standard errors for the other parameters in your model, which may result in too tight confidence intervals and reduced p-values. This can be especially troublesome if the absorbed groups vary significantly or if their effects are important in your research.

Personally I would rather use a model with random effects for a categorical variable with a very large number of levels, if you are interested in individual level inference. `PROC MIXED` and `PROC GLIMMIX` are able to fit a wide range of mixed effects models. If you are interested in population level inference then generalised estimating equations with `PROC GENMOD`.